# Error rendering a custom control in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I made some custom controls and I use them in a GridView. They inherit the BoundField class. This is the code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server" CssClass="tb" DataSourceID="ds">
    <Columns>
        <asp:StatusBoundField DataField="bstatus"  ActiveTitle="Activated"
         InactiveTitle="Inactivated" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

It works perfectly when I run the page in browser, but when I try to see it in Design View, I get this error:

GridView - grid

There was an error rendering the control. DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'bstatus'.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

you are missing an "

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server" CssClass="tb" DataSourceID="ds>
```

should be `<asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server" CssClass="tb" DataSourceID="ds">`

Comment: I changed the component names here, in my project, the " are OK.